# Having trouble editing and executing .sh file in Cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am relatively new to the Cygwin program, and I have a .sh file that I need to edit and execute. I am currently running on Windows 10. I have installed Cygwin64 terminal on my machine.

The full list of steps required are as follows:

1. Be sure to have `libtool` installed.
2. Download protobuf from https://github.com/google/protobuf/ (download ZIP and unZIP at desired location, or clone the repo) The protocol buffer is used for communication between the `CuraEngine` and the GUI.
3. Before installing protobuf, change autogen.sh : comment line 18 to line 38 using `#`s. This removes the dependency on gtest-1.7.0.
4. Run autogen.sh from the protobuf directory: `$ ./autogen.sh`
5. `$ ./configure`
6. `$ make`
7. `$ make install # Requires superused priviliges.
   (In case the shared library cannot be loaded, you can try "sudo ldconfig" on Linux systems)`

Once I get to 3.:

Before installing protobuf, change autogen.sh : comment line 18 to line 38 using `#`s. This removes the dependency on gtest-1.7.0.

I am having issues opening up to .sh file in Cygwin to make the appropriate edit.

When I try this command to even execute the .sh file:

```
$ '/cygdrive/c/Users/Thomas/Desktop/3D Printing/protobuf-master/autogen.sh'
```

I receive the error:

> Could not find source code.  Make sure you are running this script
>   from the root of the distribution tree.

If anyone has some insight as to a solution for this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess: To run `autogen.sh`. First `cd` to `/cygdrive/c/Users/Thomas/Desktop/3D Printing/protobuf-master/` and then exec the script by `./autogen.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error from this `test` in autogen.sh :

```
# Check that we're being run from the right directory.
if test ! -f src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h; then
  cat >&2 << __EOF__
Could not find source code.  Make sure you are running this script from the
root of the distribution tree.
__EOF__
```

In this `test`, `common.h` path is relative to the protbuf install directory, just `cd` to it before executing the script.